# access javascript variable outside scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{

    jQuery.get('data/php/traces_pos.csv', function(data) { var routes = jQuery.csv()(data); });

//if I use here 

for (i=0;i<=routes.length;i++){}

// javascript says route undefined

}
```

How do I access the routes which is a array of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until routes has been set. I'm using a function and passing in `routes` as a parameter:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{

    jQuery.get('data/php/traces_pos.csv', function(data) {  
        var routes = jQuery.csv()(data); 
        performRoutes(routes);
    });
});

//if I use here 
function performRoutes(routes) {
    for (i=0;i<=routes.length;i++){
        // routes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define routes outside the callback:

```
var routes;
jQuery.get('data/php/traces_pos.csv', function(data) { routes = jQuery.csv()(data); });
```

Comment: Won't help because the callback has not yet run when the OP tries to use the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define routes outside of either function, as such:

```
var routes;

jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{

    jQuery.get('data/php/traces_pos.csv', function(data) {  routes = jQuery.csv()(data); });

//if I use here 

for (i=0;i<=routes.length;i++){}

//  routes is no longer undefined

}
```

Comment: after doing that I get cannot read property length of 'undefined' in y browser

Comment: You want the length of undefined?

Comment: I am getting that error for  this line - for (i=0;i<=routes.length;i++){}

Comment: yes it is. I get an array of arrays in firebug when I do console.log. But does that mean that it really doesnt have a property called length?

Comment: I would say this is now out of the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

Moving the declaration of `routes` outside the `jQuery.get` call will make it *visible* to your for loop -- but **beware** that your for loop runs *before the callback is called*, so `routes` will not have been set yet.

Anything you do that depends on the result of an asynchronous get **must** be either *inside the callback function* or *in code that is called from within the callback function*. In the latter case, you can pass your routes as a parameter at the function call -- there is no need to widen the variable's scope.

Comment: cant I just wait till the callback is finished? Otherwise my whole program which is dependent on routes will end up being in the jquery.get

Comment: The way to wait until the callback is called is to _do your work inside the callback_. That's what it's _for_. There's no good cross-browser supported way to block the thread until something happens in JavaScript. (Doing so would be likely to halt the entire JS engine).